# Php Post Action

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, action

I want to post my action according to select entries. However, my code does not work. How can I do? Thank you.

```
 <form action=<?php echo $filename; ?> method="post">
<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="A" onclick="selecta()" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="B" onclick="selectb()" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="select" value="C" onclick="selectc()" />
    </form>
    <?php
        function selecta(){
            $filename = "a.php";
        }
        function selectb(){
            $filename = "b.php";
        }
        function selectc(){
            $filename = "c.php";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You're mixing client-side code with server-side code.  In the browser, there are no such functions as `selecta()`, `selectb()`, or `selectc()`.  The JavaScript console is probably giving you that exact error, that the functions aren't found.  It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish, but you have to do it either client-side or server-side, the two can't mix.

Comment: My problem is that form action does not take filename value.

Comment: Yes, that's because `$filename` doesn't *have* a value when that code executes.  Because server-side code executes on the server, *before* the page is sent to the browser.

Comment: What I have to do? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Which is what, exactly?

Comment: I am taking select types and according to select types I want to go ".php" url.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PHP to dynamically change HTML. Use JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
<br/><input type="submit" name="select" value="A" onclick="selecta()"/>
<br/><input type="submit" name="select" value="B" onclick="selectb()"/>
<br/><input type="submit" name="select" value="C" onclick="selectc()"/>
</form>
<script>
var action = 'a.php';
$(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        $(this).attr('action', action);
    });
});
function selecta() {
    action = 'a.php';
}
function selectb() {
    action = 'b.php';
}
function selectc() {
    action = 'c.php';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this code on server side, since you are using PHP

```
  <?php 

    $filename = '';


    $files =
    [
        'A' => 'a',
        'B' => 'b',
        'C' => 'c',
    ]

    if( !empty( $_POST['select'] ) )
    {
        if( isset( $files[ $_POST['select'] ] ) )
        {
          $filename = $files[ $_POST['select'] ].'.php';
        }
    }

    ?>

    <form action= "<?php echo $filename; ?>" method="post"> <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="select" value="A"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="select" value="B"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="select" value="C" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Route::get('anyString','UserController@profile');

- When you type anyString on url then it call UserController Profile
  method.